# Find members of Active Directory Domain Group

Tags: windows, security, active-directory

What's the easiest way to check the members of an AD Domain Group from a Windows XP or Server 2003 computer?

Preferably this would be a gui, or a one line console command (not a script).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Active Directory Users and Computers" comes to mind.

It's dsa.msc and is available as part of the Windows Server adminpak.

http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?familyid=86B71A4F-4122-44AF-BE79-3F101E533D95&displaylang=en

Comment: Great, a new favorite tool!

Answer (score 1):

Open Active Directory Users and Computers then
go to the properties of the group and click on the Members tab...

Comment: Where do I "Open Active Directory Users and Computers"

Comment: You have to install it on non-DC servers and client systems; it's in adminpak.msi, available on the Windows Server 2003 CD-ROM or from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly what your looking for. It's a free download from Microsoft. You can find it here:

Windows Server 2003 Administration Tools Pack:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C16AE515-C8F4-47EF-A1E4-A8DCBACFF8E3&displaylang=en

It's full of all kinds of useful tools, and usually comes installed wherever there is a domain controller. Under the Administrative Tools there is one called "Active Directory Users and Computers". You can search for the group. Opening it up there is a "Members" tab that will list all user's in the group.

Comment: It's actually the "Members" tab, not the "Members Of" tab.  Big difference in one little word.  :-)